# Dispatch multiple action in redux middleware

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action, middleware

I have this React Native app along with redux where all HTTP requests are performed through async actions using [redux-promise-middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware).

Now I want to handle every error that can be sent by the API and for that I'm implementing a redux middleware that will intercept every action with the type `XXX_REJECTED` (since [redux-promise-middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware) dispatches a `_REJECTED` action when an async action fails).

But now I have this problem... In the middleware I want to be able to dispatch a new action (a `API_ERROR` for instance) and still be able to perform `next()` for the original action (the `XXX_REJECTED`).

Here's my middleware:

```
export default ({ dispatch }) => next => (action) => {
  if (action.type.match(/w*(_REJECTED)/)) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'API_ERROR',
      payload: action.payload,
    })
  }

  next(action)
}
```

But with this code once the new action is dispatched, the `next()` is never executed.

Does this make sense? Is it possible to dispatch multiple actions in a middleware?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to return the next action. And yes you should be able to dispatch as many actions as you want.

```
return next(action)
```

Comment: Many thanks for that! Really appreciated.

But actually I've found that everything was ok with the middleware. The problem was in the reducer :/ My bad.

And be aware that `dispatch` does not return a promise, so you can't chain it with `.then`.

But thank you for your help! :D

Comment: I thought your middleware was for async actions. Oh well yeah then don't chain it with `.then` then :D

Answer (score 0):

Found that everything was ok with the middleware. You can dispatch as many actions as you wish.

My mistake was in the reducer, where I had a `case` with no state returned from it (only a `console.log(action)`).

My bad!